# Maven : Build Issues in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a Maven project which has sub-modules in it and in each modules there are different profiles like spark2.x, spark 3.x, kafka1.x and so on

Now i have different source folders for profiles and suppose I have a class say ConfigLoader.class which is present in each profile and based on profile you build you will get a different flavor of that class based on the profile.

When I build through maven cli -
I don't get any compile time issues and it builds successfully as I mention the profile that I want to build in the command.
command

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip -Dcobertura.skip -Pspark3.0,dev -Denforcer.skip=true -Dcheckstyle.skip=true
```

1. When same thing I try with intellij, then I get compile time error stating duplicate files and then manually I have to unmark the irrelavant profile as source directory, is ther any way intellij picks this up automatically ?
2. I have a main program inside Module 1, I want to test my code snippet by simply running that main program instead of deploying the complete war, when I run this in intellij is give me error saying "java: package com.foobar.json doesnot exist."
   Although the above mention package is nothing but a package which sits inside Module 2 which gets compile/build successfully.

Can someone suggest what cna I do to run that specific Java Prgram which has main method even with the error.

Also if someone can suggest how to resolve the two problems it will be great.

Project structure -

```
    Parent 
         - Module 1
           - maven profiles 
             - spark 2.x
             - spark 3.x
         - Module 2 
           - maven profiles 
             - spark 2.x
             - spark 3.x
```

Comment: IntelliJ cares about much much more than standard Maven with javac.   Don’t have multiple classes with the exact same name on the classpath. That’s brittle.  Use a standard configuration tool instead. Property files are usually fine for this.

Comment: I agree same names class should be avoided but this is a legacy code I am talking about in my organization can't help it.
Is there any solution for my problem?

Comment: If it is legacy code, then presumably it has worked before.  Why was it changed from something that worked?

Comment: Not sure, On Ubuntu using Maven Command, even with the same code this builds perfect, but with Eclipse or any other IDE this doesn't and even on my local Maven command.